# EXCEL: Create/delete rows with autofilled data/functions matching to a number in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that I have a small formula which have a minimum of 2 rows and should be able to be expanded to a given number from another cell. E.g. 2 rows minimum - then the cell numbering the amount of rows is set to 10. Then there will be added another 8 rows between row 1 & 2. With autofilled data that is similar to when you drag it down using the autofill option.
Again when you set down the number from 10 to 4 then 6 of the rows should be deleted.

Hope that you can see the idea of what I am thinking and again I'm very sorry if this is unclear or not fulfilling all requirements to a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Define three named cells -- say, `FirstCell`, `LastCell` and `HowMany`. Make sure `LastCell` is right below `FirstCell`.
2. Create a `Worksheet_Change` handler. If the `Target` range is the `HowMany` cell, then add or remove cells between `FirstCell` and `LastCell`:

   ```
   If Target.Address = Me.Range("HowMany").Address Then
     If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
       If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
         If Target.Value >= 2 Then

           Dim i As Long
           Dim rows_before As Long

           rows_before = Me.Range("LastCell").Row - Me.Range("FirstCell").Row + 1

           If rows_before < Target.Value Then
             For i = 1 To Target.Value - rows_before
               Me.Range("LastCell").Insert xlShiftDown
             Next
           ElseIf rows_before > Target.Value Then
             Me.Range(Me.Range("LastCell").Offset(-1, 0), Me.Range("LastCell").Offset(-(rows_before - Target.Value), 0)).Delete xlShiftUp
           End If

           Me.Range(Me.Range("FirstCell"), Me.Range("LastCell")).FillDown
         End If
       End If
     End If
   End If
   ```

Comment: Thank you! - I will try to see if I can learn how to implement this, I never tried use VB. So this will be a challenge :) - Have a nice weekend so far! :)